# Out of range when creating a vector

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector

I have a map defined as:

```
map<std::string,std::vector<string> > followers
```

where the string refers to a username, and the vector of strings to the ones that username follows. So for adding a new follower, I made this code:

```
std::vector<string> following = followers.at(recvbuf_usrn);
following.push_back(recvbuf_usrn2);
followers[recvbuf_usrn] = following;
```

where `recvbuf_usrn` is defined as `std::string recvbuf_usrn` so as `recvbuf_usrn2`

When debugging, I get an error in

```
std::vector<string> following = followers.at(recvbuf_usrn);
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x779BDAD8 in Server.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0018F4A0.

I tried to make `map<std::string,std::vector<string *> > followers` but unsuccessfully. What could I do? Is it better to use a vector or a list?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like the `std::out_of_range` is coming from *the map's* `at`. Does `followers` have an entry for `recvbuf_usrn`?

Comment: You are right. It didn't have any entry. I made an entry for another map, but this one was empty. Thanks!

Comment: (OT: Shouldn't it be `map<std::string, std::set<string> >`?)

Answer (score 1):

The object does not seem to exist in your vector already. `at` necessitates that it already exists. What you probably want is `operator[]`, so try replacing:

```
std::vector<string> following = followers.at(recvbuf_usrn);
```

with

```
std::vector<string>& following = followers[recvbuf_usrn];
```

Please also note, that I added `&` because you would otherwise just work on a copy of the vector, which is probably not what you desire.

Also note Jarod42`s comment which makes your code even leaner.

Comment: `followers[recvbuf_usrn] = following;` is then unneeded. and code can even be written as `followers[recvbuf_usrn].push_back(recvbuf_usrn2);`

Comment: This solution is quite better. The problem was that the map was empty, but for pushing back an element i was getting a copy, push back that copy and then replace it from the original in the map. With that solution I avoid this last step. Thanks!!